# Data Validation List containing matching data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is my problem -

The first table contains a list of questions 
[image]

while the second contains a list of answers

[image]

What I'd like to do is have a drop down list in each Response column that contains only the relevant answers from responses table. In order to do that i'm trying to have a generic formula which finds all matching response_tbl[QID] to questions_tbl[ID] and brings back response_tbl[Answer Text]

But i'm having much trouble with it for quite some time. I'd much appreciate any help on the matter

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can sort the answer table by QID then I would have a solution. Create a named range

```
=OFFSET(Answers!D$1;MATCH(Questions!A2;Answers!$A$2:$A$10;0);0;COUNTIF(Answers!$A$2:$A$10;Questions!A2);1)
```

where Answers is list containing QID in A column and Answer in C colum. Quastions is list containing questions with ID in A and the dropdown in D.
After you create the name range click D2 in Questions sheet go to data validation, select list and enter "=NamedRange" without " and with the name of your named range. Now if you copy it down to other questions it will fetch correct answers for the questions, because the Questions!A2 is without $ in the named range.